# Laravel Mix throws error when trying to run it on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, npm, laravel-mix

I have a Laravel project, which perfectly runs on : macOS, that I am trying to run on Ubuntu 20.04.

When I run :

```
npm run dev
```

I get the following error:

```
> @development /home/my-user/workspace/my-project
> npm run development
> @development /home/my-user/workspace/my-project
> mix

/home/my-user/workspace/my-project/node_modules/laravel-mix/bin/cli.js:39
            executeScript('watch', { ...program.opts(), ...opts }, cmd.args)
                                     ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `mix`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/my-user/.npm/_logs/2022-04-19T09_37_49_114Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/my-user/.npm/_logs/2022-04-19T09_37_49_120Z-debug.log
```

code versions:

```
npm 5.0.0 
nvm 0.39.1
node 8.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your node version doesn't support spread operator. Use version 8.3 or higher.